# Which has greater precedence, filter rule or bucket rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking into [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-ex1) and I wonder, if I have bucket policies setup too, which will take precedence?
For example if I have the bucket 'bucky' and have expiration policy on it for 10 days and also setup a filter on '/foo' for No expiration at all. Will the files under 'foo' be deleted after 10 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some [reading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-conceptual-ex5) it turns out that, when prefixes are overlapping (in my case, empty prefix overlaps with 'foo') AWS chooses the policy that will transition/expire objects the earliest.

> Generally, Amazon S3 Lifecycle optimizes for cost. For example, if two expiration policies overlap, the shorter expiration policy is honored so that data is not stored for longer than expected.